# Can Alt codes (emojis) be in Active Directory password?

Tags: active-directory

Is Active Directory able to hash alt codes such as `☺` (Alt 1)? Will using alt codes in my password cause issues in Active Directory?

Comment: AD will be fine with, whether connected systems that rely on AD for authentication will accept it is a whole other question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements#:%7E:text=The%20password%20contains%20characters%20from%20three%20of%20the%20following%20categories%3A) shows a list of character sets, but only says that at least 3 of those are required when the "Passwords must meet complexity requirements" setting is enabled. That list doesn't include emojis, but it also doesn't explicitly say that other characters are not allowed.

[This random Twitter user](https://twitter.com/TypePromiscuous/status/1136829599873003520) says it's possible:

> Active directory supports full unicode passwords including emoji, I know this because reasons...

But be warned: [this guy](https://davidzych.com/abusing-emoji-in-windows/#:%7E:text=your%20home%20directory%3A-,Passwords,-You%20can%20also) says:

> But just like in OSX, it's almost impossible to enter emoji at the login screen so sadly you can't sign in with that password.

This article describes why it's a bad idea in general, but the focus is on Mac: [Why you should (not) use Emoji in your passwords](https://medium.com/@hvost/why-you-should-not-use-emojis-in-your-passwords-b8db0607e169)

So it seems the answer is yes, you can. But just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.